# Deprecated: preg_replace() to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, replace, deprecated

I'm having trouble understanding the preg_replace_callback function that I should use instead of the current preg_replace() lines I have.

How could I modify the following lines with preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace() ? :

```
$message = preg_replace('/\\[' . $tag . '\\](.*)\\[\/' . $tag . '\\]/siU', $this->tagparser->$parser('\\1'), $message);

$message = preg_replace("/\[" . $tag . "=(&quot;|\"|'|)([0-9,\s]+)\\1\](.*)\[\/" . $tag . "\]/siU", $replace2, $message);

$output = preg_replace('#All rights reserved.#i', 'All rights reserved.', $output, 1, $match);
```

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: That first line looks like something that wouldn't work in any PHP version. Are you sure those are your original statements? I'm assuming you were using the `e` flag, which doesn't appear in the code you posted. Also, did you take a look at the [manual for `preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)?

Comment: they are taken from a more complete php file, I just extracted the lines that have to be modified.

Comment: Well, in this case, your `$this->tagparser->$parser` method takes `\\1` (literally) as its argument. That only works if you return it back in some different form (like concatenating stuff to it), but that's very weird/dubious. Also, since you're not using the `e` flag, what makes you think it's deprecated? Can you paste the actual error/notice message you're getting?

Comment: This is the error I have : preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in page.php

Comment: Well, then you didn't post the line(s) that error was referring to. You're not using the `e` flag in any of those lines.